# Jolt transformation from array to one-to-many

Tags: json, jolt

This is my input json, which is array of user and devices

```
{
  "q": [
    {
      "UserId": "3000",
      "SiteId": "website1",
      "CreateDate": "2022-04-01T08:26:21.401Z",
      "DevideId": "ddd1111",
      "TokenId": "abcd1234"
    },
    {
      "UserId": "3000",
      "SiteId": "website1",
      "CreateDate": "2022-04-01T08:26:21.401Z",
      "DevideId": "ddd2222",
      "TokenId": "wxyz1234"
    },
    {
      "UserId": "3002",
      "SiteId": "website1",
      "CreateDate": "2022-04-01T08:26:21.401Z",
      "DevideId": "ddd333",
      "TokenId": "wxyz1234"
    }
  ]
}
```

output json should be:

```json
[
      {
        "CreateDate": "2022-04-01T08:26:21.401Z",
        "UserId": "3000",
        "devices": [
          {
            "DevideId": "ddd1111",
            "SiteId": "website1",
            "TokenId": "abcd1234"
          },
          {
            "DevideId": "ddd2222",
            "SiteId": "website1",
            "TokenId": "wxyz1234"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "CreateDate": "2022-04-01T08:26:21.401Z",
        "UserId": "3002",
        "devices": [
          {
            "DevideId": "ddd333",
            "SiteId": "website1",
            "TokenId": "wxyz1234"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

And the output JSON (one user, multiple devices) means array of user-device (one to many relation)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following transformation spec

```json
[
  { // to seperate those two attributes to the outer level
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "q": {
        "*": {
          "UserId|CreateDate": "&",
          "*": "devices[#2].&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // pick only one components from each arrays generated from the two attribues
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "UserId": "ONE",
      "CreateDate": "ONE"
    }
  },
  { // just to sort regarding the array in the result to be displayed at the bottom
    "operation": "sort"
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

**Edit** : You can use the following spec based on the new case :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "q": {
        "*": {
          "UserId|CreateDate": "@1,UserId.&",
          "*": "@1,UserId.devices[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "UserId": "ONE",
        "CreateDate": "ONE"
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of redundantly generated null values
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  },
  { // write the attributes and "devices" seperately in order to be able sort attributes at the top
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "CreateDate|UserId": "[#2].&",
        "devices": "[#2].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer,  This is not working if i hava another user with different device, it should come as another structure with one device
{
      "UserId": "3002",
      "SiteId": "website1",
      "CreateDate": "2022-04-01T08:26:21.401Z",
      "DevideId": "ddd333",
      "TokenId": "wxyz1234"
    }

Comment: @Teegen Can you please edit the question to show what you have as input and desired output based on this new case

Comment: I edited now, but somehow output json showing without structure after saving changes

Comment: Can you please check now.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Teegen OK, I've just added the new case

Comment: I  marked it.. Thanks again, you saved my time.. Best Regards :)